# What's that book about an animal eating cube

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

I will do my best to describe this. I read this book around 2010~2012, and I lost it during hurricane Sandy so it could not have come out later than Oct 2012.
White cover, minimal illustrations and all done in black ink, think Shel Silverstein style cartoons.
The most I can remember was that there was this all powerful entity, a giant floating cube with a mouth. And at some point it slurps up a large portion of the world's animals. Like a string of spaghetti almost? Maybe it's more of a prison but I can swear remembering it eating them.
There is an illustration of this cube having a large mouth on one of its sides, very wrinkled and detailed. It's plastered onto the underside of it, eating different exotic animals as it floats over the ground.
I would appreciate any guesses whatsover, this book is **haunting** me.

Comment: I do not believe it was part of any series, I remember it as a stand alone novel. I do not remember if it took place in any one location and it did not particularly mention China or any cultural reference explicit to ancient China.

Comment: Coming back to this to clarify a few other details I remembered. This large cube had lips and didn't start it's feasting until midway through the book? If there were main characters they weren't repeatedly illustrated. I will also say it wasn't a scifi novel so no spaceships.